# Axis constraint for Coreplot axis set in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, axis, core-plot

Currently I'm converting objective-C based plotting app to the swift and most of the parts are knife in the butter, but I'm struck when it comes to the **axis positioning**.

In objective-C I used the below two lines to **fix the axis on the plot**,

```c
CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *)graph.axisSet;
CPTXYAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;

x.orthogonalPosition = @0.0
x.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintsWithLowerOffset: 0.0];
```

The problem here is, the swift implementation is void of these two properties

- orthogonalPosition
- axisConstraints

So, if anybody knows the correct way of doing this or any workaround for fixing the axis in the plot kindly provide a helping hand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
x.orthogonalPosition = 0.0
x.axisConstraints = CPTConstraints(lowerOffset: 0.0)
```